# Accessing view directly with ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I create a new view I can't access to it with direct link. I have to access to "home" or "test" (two buttons in the navbar) and then i can past the link and access. I also can do it with href="newview..." in one of the other views, but not directly

```
  angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch']).config(function($stateProvider) {
  return $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "home.html"
  }).state('test', {
    url: "/test",
    templateUrl: "test.html"
  }).state('test.child', {
    url: "/:id",
    templateUrl: "child.html"
  }).state('otherwise', {
    url: "/notfound",
    templateUrl: "notfound.html"
  });
});
```

so if I try `#/test/3456` it don't work I have a blank page, same with `#/notfound`, but if I put them if `<a href".....>` in one of the other views, or if I access first one of the other views, it works fine. Test and notfound views contain just sone html code `<b> test not found </b>`